# How do I show a field in dispform that's been hidden in content type?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, jquery, word, dip

Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise. This is document library for word documents. I have some fields that are set by workflow that I want end user to see but not be able to edit.

I was going to just use JQuery on the right forms, but field still loads in Document Information Panel in Word.

I found that hiding field under content type settings removes it from DIP, but now it's not on dispform. I was hoping the hide option would just hide it in HTML (so I could show it with Jquery), but it looks like it is not rendered at all.

So how can I display a field in dispform that's been hidden in content type?

or

How can I hide DIP in Word completely? (I'd be fine with field being optional and hiding it with script if there is some way I can lock it down in Word DIP). I tried custom DIP in infopath but this throws an error as our end users don't have infopath so custom DIP won't load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the powershell script below while working on a different project. I am adding it in case someone else runs into the same problem I did. Vague do this and do that does no one any good.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/647760/Hiding-SharePoint-list-field-column-from-newform-a
By Praveen Chandran, 3 Sep 2013

```
$WebUrl = "http://sitecollectionurl"
Write-Host "Opening Web" $WebUrl
$web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl


$list = $web.Lists["ListName"];


$FieldGuid = New-Object System.Guid("cc9576b6-a166-47c9-bd89-7f47a3237e03");
$Field = $list.Fields[$FieldGuid];

$Field.ShowInNewForm = $false;
$Field.ShowInDisplayForm = $true;
$Field.ShowInEditForm = $false

$Field.Update();

$list.Update();
<span style="font-size: 14px; white-space: normal;">
</span>
```

Here, replace the `$WebUrl` with your site collection URL, and replace the `"ListName"` with your SPList name.

And replace the Guid `"cc9576b6-a166-47c9-bd89-7f47a3237e03"` with the id of the field to be hidden.

For getting the id of the field , you can use 'SharePoint Manager' tool. Its from codeplex and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a custom column you created, you should use ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" to hide it from the DIP. With ShowInDiplayForm="TRUE" will still show it in the display form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543225.aspx

Comment: That sounds good. How would I go about changing this?

Comment: You can do it by powershell, or in c# code. Grab the content type, make it visible again then change the showindisplayform and showinfiledlg properties. Or if you created the column declaratively and alble to delete and recreate you could add the properties to the XML there.

Comment: I will confess that other than working through browser gui, web parts, jquery, and workflows, my knowledge is limited. Could you walk me through basic step by step or maybe point me to step by step resource for this? I understand how powershell and c# work at very high level but I don't know how to integrate this code into my doc library. Thanks for your time!